# consider every word in elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider this phrase: `lorem ipsum quid`.

I want to query multiple fields and prefer the answers where all words are present. In other words, I don't want to ignore some words, I want to boost queries that considers all the words.

I can reach this goal by doing a `simple_query_string` and adding `+` before every word:

```
query: {
  simple_query_string: {
    query: "lorem +ipsum +quid",
    default_operator: "and",
    fields: ["f1", "f2", "f3"]
  }
}
```

Still, it seems weird, and it force me to edit the user query and replace via regex the spaces by `+`, which is a kind of tinkering.

Is there a way with elasticsearch to force (in match or multi_match or something I don't know) consideration of every words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this will done your job or not but make a try like this way- `term` inside `must`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "f1": "lorem ipsum quid"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "f2": "lorem ipsum quid"
          }
        },
       {
          "term": {
            "f3": "lorem ipsum quid"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```